# How to update kernel to 5.18 to get intel thread director

Tags: upgrade, kernel, intel, 22.04

I've been a happy (K)Ubuntu LTS user for a while now. I've recently upgraded to kubuntu 22.04 at work (still waiting on my home devices). I did this in part because I was recently given a new workstation with an Intel 12700K processor. I was expecting this processor to have 20 threads, since the p-cores should have SMT-2, and the e-cores would be single threaded, but all the cores are running single threaded. Also, it's not totally obvious that my OS even knows they're different types of cores.

I [googled](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-thread-director-coming-to-linux-5-18) [around](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-HFI-For-Linux-5.18), and found that kernel features that (on the face of it) address these issues are coming in 5.18...which might get put into a non-LTS version bump some time in the distant future, but is [apparently not coming to 22.04, or HWE updates later in life](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-2204-ryzen5950x&num=1). It looks like this will come out in a handful of days, but if I wait I may have a different workstation by the time it winds up in an LTS/HWE release.

So how bad of an idea is it to upgrade my kernel? How would I go about doing that, while doing the least amount of damage to my shiny new 22.04 install?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: "*but is definitely not coming to 22.04*"  are you sure?  I don't follow kernel notices that closely; but I wasn't aware the *kinetic* kernel  was '*locked in concrete*' ... given later non-LTS kernels become the prior cycle's LTS HWE kernel stacks..  The next kernel freeze isn't until 6-Oct-2022 (*though kernel should be known earlier than that*) so you must have a good *crystal ball*..

Comment: One of the articles I googled simply said something about this. I was surprised; it seems like not having this feature in the LTS kernel would be bad. I don't have a crystal ball. If you know how to check such things that would be helpful. I do not.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS being a LTS release always releases with a LTS kernel. 5.15 LTS was the most recent LTS kernel prior to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS's release, so why would you expect it to release with a non-LTS kernel?  Didn't you want Ubuntu 22.04 to be a LTS or *long-term-support* release.  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS will use the kernel stack from 22.10, 22.04.3 LTS will use the kernel stack from 23.04, 22.04.4 from 23.10, 22.04.5 kernel stack from 24.04 LTS (a LTS kernel) just like prior LTS releases if using HWE; ie what kernels they are are still unknown - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I don't expect it to release with a non-LTS kernel. I want to use a kernel that supports my hardware correctly, so am accepting that I may need to _not_ use an LTS kernel anymore. It's really a bummer that the unsupported hardware is the current processor series from intel. If what you're trying to communicate to me is that 5.18 may be a minor version bump Kernel for the LTS series at some point in the future. I'm trying to tell you that based on my interpretation of that phoronix article, there's no specific plan to do that and the plans extend about one year. 22.10 is likely to include 5.17.

Comment: Michael (phoronix) tends to watch the Ubuntu kernel team much more closely than I do.  Canonical/Ubuntu tend to have *edge* kernels available month+ before they're available for general use (via -proposed etc) and I I'd opt for them if I could over *testing* kernels via PPA; but your use-case means the kernel team PPA will likely get it faster. Personally I'd likely have searched or possibly asked on this thread (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ask-us-anything-about-ubuntu-kernels/27664)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Debian/Ubuntu Kernel packages from this URL:

[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

Make sure to download install the needed module and header packages, too.

Usually you can select a kernel you want to boot on startup in Grub. Going back to a standard kernel should be easily possible.

But I don't know all details about you system and I will not give any guarantee. So make sure you have a recent backup of your valuable data and some time to recover in case something went wrong !!

This is not a real Debian repo. You have to install the packages manually. For Debian admins, this is some kind of basic knowledge needed for their work. I guess there is no step by step docu.

**AGAIN:** if you are not that experienced that you do not really know how to do it, make sure you have a backup and a plan B in case of failures. These kernels are **untested** and could destroy your system in worst case. Better start learning how to use `dpkg` (`man dpkg`).

Install:

1. Download at least the `linux-image-unsigned...` and `linux-modules...`
2. Install `linux-modules`: `dpkg -i linux-modules...`
3. Install `linux-image-unsigned`: `dpkg -i linux-image-unsigned...`
4. (optional) install the headers: `dpkg -i linux-headers... linux-headers...generic...`

Of course, you have to fill the dots with what you downloaded. And you have to reboot to activate the kernel.

Comment: Presumably there's a way to interact with that ppa with apt, but what would the workflow be?

Comment: No, there isn't way to use apt for that.

Comment: How do I 'install' the files from the link, and determine the correct module and header packages. Is there some documentation somewhere?